# Is it possible to send date of transaction (not today) using Google Measurement Protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I build application which pull sales data from Amazon and push it to Google Analytics.

I'm "hitting" transaction to Analytics and it's all works fine, the problem is that in Amazon the sales data updated after 48 hours (maximum) so I need to pull the report two days later.

Does anyone know if there's a way to send the date of the transaction? Can't find it in the Measurement Protocol API.

Thank you all, Peace and love :)

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You have the queue time parameter (offset between current time and time the data was tracked), but as it says [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt):

> Values greater than four hours may lead to hits not being processed.

"May" indicates that this is not a completely fixed limit but I'm pretty sure that 48 hours are not covered (Philipp Walton, a Google engineer who frequents SO once mentioned that the queue time limit is somehow related to timezones and rollover between days, so I'd guess that two days are way to long).

Apart from that there is as of yet no way to set a date for a hit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Do you know if it possible to add transactions to data import CSV file somehow?

Comment: No (unless as a custom dimension, but that is most probably not what you want, since this would not change the original hit date; it would simply add a field with the actual transaction date). More to the point, unless you have an Analytics 360 account with query time imports the upload needs to happen before the hit which is in this case not possible.

Comment: Yeah...that's what i thought. Thank you again mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try posting a Custom Dimension for each event you send, where the dimension is formatted to the date-time:-

e.g. 
&t=event&cd1=20170423081321&cm1=24 etc

Only problem is: when you generate a GA custom report, the values are accumulated per day. If anyone knows how to get round that, would love to hear it!